# How to check if current unit test has a particular attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, unit-testing, testing

In my unit tests I need to test queries to a database (no I am not mocking these, as I need to check they get the correct data).  I also have normal methods that do not contact a database at all and some methods that I can use a mock to the database.

To cope with the database unit tests, I created a class called `DbUnitTest`, which each unit test class (for a service) can inherit from if it needs to connect to a database.

This class looks like so

```
[TestClass]
public abstract class DbUnitTest
{
    protected IDataContext _context;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInit()
    {
        _context = new DataContext();

        // drop if exists
        if (_context.Database.Exists())
            _context.Database.Delete();

        // initialize
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new ForceDeleteInitializer(new DbUnitTestInitializer()));

        _context.Database.Initialize(true);
    }

}
```

This works, and for each test it deletes the database and creates a new one. I can then insert whatever data I want within each unit test and check that the data is correct.

But now some of my service classes that I am unit testing, do not need a real database, so it seems pointless to delete the database, initialize it etc etc as this takes time.

I thought maybe I could create an attribute against each test, like UseDb and UseMock.  Then in my base DbUnitTest class, I could change the method to something like this

```
[TestClass]
public abstract class DbUnitTest
{
    protected IDataContext _dbContext;
    protected Mock<IDataContext> _mockContext;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInit()
    {
        // How do I check for an attribute here??
        if (method has UseDb attribute)
        {
            _dbContext = new DataContext();

            // drop if exists
            if (_dbContext.Database.Exists())
                .Database.Delete();

            // initialize
            System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new ForceDeleteInitializer(new DbUnitTestInitializer()));

            _dbContext.Database.Initialize(true);
        }

        if (UseMock attribute)
        {
            // mock context
            _mockContext = new Mock<IDataContext>();
        }
    }

}
```

But I am unsure of how, or if it is possible to determine if the current unit test method that is running contains a particular attribute?

This would then give me the benefit of each test being able to either create a new database or use a mock.

Can anyone help me?

I know I could really split the Unit Test classes up into 2 files, but thought this would keep all tests for a service in one place and offers flexibility.

Comment: I was going to suggest a multi file approach - but I see you've considered that. Can't offer anything by way of a solution - but I'd be interested to see if there is another way around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using MS test runner.  If you are, then you can add a `TestContext` property to your class:

```
public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }
```

This will be populated by the test engine when it runs your tests.  In your test initialize, you can then use the `TestContext.Name` property to identify the name of the test that is currently running.  So you could do something like this to check for an attribute on the test method:

```
var useDbAttr = GetType().GetMethod(TestContext.TestName)
                         .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(UseDbAttribute), true);
if(useDbAttr.Length > 0) {
    // Setup for DB calls
} else {
    // Setup for mocked calls
}
```

Comment: Love this, but i went down the separate files root in the end as needed to do it quickly, and was running out of time.  Great answer though!